# Java: Enum value at compile time?

Tags: java, enums

How do I fetch the value string of an enum at compile time? If I do EnumType.EnumVar.value(), it's resolved at runtime. I want this is to be obtained at compile time so that I can use it in Switch case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't, basically. If you want to use enums in a switch, you should parse the string value to an enum value, and then switch on that. If the value may not be in the enum, consider creating a `Map<String, EnumType>` so that you can perform the conversion quickly without the `IllegalArgumentException` that `EnumType.valueOf(String)` would throw.

Comment: Thanks for the note Jon. Digressing, but any reason why its not allowed? Any thoughts on why the design to disable getting textual value of a enum at compile time?

Comment: @ChandraMohan: I suspect because it would make the language more complicated for very little benefit.

Comment: @ChandraMohan Just like you shouldn't use a String to represent a date or a number, you shouldn't use a String to represent an instance of your enumerated type. Use the enum. The string to enum conversion should be done when getting input from an external source (the user, a file, whatever), and the enum to string conversion should be done when sending output to an external source. Inside the code, Use the enum instances.